# Constant based on variable?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, xna, constants

I'm making a small game in XNA at the moment.

And I want to base the size of an array on my screen's resolution.

I did it like this:

```
public const int intBoardheight = (GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height -150) / 10 ;
public const int intBoardwidth = (GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width - 200) / 10;

public bool[,] GameBoard = new bool[intBoardheight,intBoardwidth];
public bool[,] GameBoardUpdate = new bool[intBoardheight, intBoardwidth];
public int[,] GameBoardInt = new int[intBoardheight, intBoardwidth];
```

But this gives me the error "The expression being assigned to 'Game_Of_Life_2.Game1.intBoardheight' must be constant".

So, how do I base a constant on a variable?

Thanks in advance!

Simon.

EDIT:
Thanks guys! Worked very well!

Comment: A constant is something that *never* changes. Not something that *never changes during the life of a program.* *Never* as in "not at any point in time, past, present, or future, will this value ever be any different than what it says right here." Pi is a constant. 1 is a constant. `CurrentDisplayMode.Height` is not constant.

Comment: Um, it's a variable if you're basing it on a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Make it a `public static readonly int`

Comment: I vote for this, I think static readonly better expresses the idea of "constant" than just readonly (which could be changed by each class instance in its constructor).

Answer (score 1):

You can not create a constant but you can make it readonly

```
public readonly int intBoardheight = ...
```

A `readonly` variable can only be assigned at the declaration or in the constructor. After that it is not possible to change.

Answer (score 1):

since it's variable - based on the current resolution *when you run your app* - you cannot make this a compile time constant but you can make it `readonly`.